# How can I put all the URL parameters in array of objects using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a giving string/url like this
`https://example.com/loadcontent?var1=100&var2=:somevar&var3=:morevariables`

I need to loop thought each parameter in the url. If the value starts with `:` this indicated that it is a variable an I will need to change that value dynamically by looking at the corresponding meta attribute that matches that variable.

Here is my code in which loops over an array and sets the value of the parameters.

```
    var baseURL = getBaseURL(url);

    var params = getParams(url);
    var newParams = $.each(params, function(index, param){

       if( param.value.substring(0, 1) == ':'){
           var myVar = param.value.substring(1);
           param.value = $('meta[name=" + myVar + "']).attr('value');
       }

    });

    var finalURL = baseURL + '?' + jQuery.param( newParams );

function getParams(url){
  // This function should return an array of objects. Each object should have 2 properties "value" and "name". The "name" property should be the name of the parameter (ie. var1, var2, var3 .....) and the "value" attribute should contains the value of the parameter (ie. 100, :somevar, :morevariables)


}

function getBaseURL(url){

  var cutoff = url.indexOf('?');

  if( cutoff > -1){
     return url.substring(0, cutoff - 1);
  }

  return url;

}
```

I need help converting the parameters of a giving URL to array of object. How can I do this in jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: @Andreas thank you for your feedback. but how can I get that code to put all the parameters into an array of objects? It seems to allow me to get one giving parameter at a time

Comment: Don't just look for the accepted answer ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929/402037

Comment: @Andreas thank you. you provided me the help I need to solve it. If you post an answer I will accept it

Comment: Because I've voted to close this question ("_Possible duplicate of..._") I won't add it as an answer :)

Comment: Are you sure that `[ {name: k1, value: v1}, { name: k2, value: v2}, ...]` is what you're after?  A straight map of key/value pairs would be more usual.

Comment: I just voted to close it as well.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need jQuery for this one.

```
function getParams(url) {

        var queryString = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1);
        var paramsArr = queryString.split('&');
        var params = [];

        for (var i = 0, len = paramsArr.length; i < len; i++) {
            var keyValuePair = paramsArr[i].split('=');
            params.push({
                name: keyValuePair[0],
                value: keyValuePair[1]
            });
        }

        return params;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using map

```js
var url = 'https://example.com/loadcontent?var1=100&var2=:somevar&var3=:morevariables&test';

function getParamArray(url) {
  var queryString = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("?") + 1);

  return queryString.split('&').map(function(sParam) {
    var param = sParam.split('=');

    return {
      name: param[0],
      value: decodeURIComponent(param[1])
    };
  });
}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(getParamArray(url), null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a regular expresion and JSON.parse:

```
 var url = 'https://example.com/loadcontent?var1=100&var2=:somevar&var3=:morevariables';

url = url.replace(/^.*\?/,'');
url = url.replace(/(\w+)=?([\w:]*)/g,'{"name":"$1","value":"$2"}');
url = url.replace(/&/g,',');

var paramsObject = JSON.parse("["+url+"]");


/*
Returns: 

Array [{"name":"var1","value":"100"},{"name":"var2","value":":somevar"},{"name":"var3","value":":morevariables"}];
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need JQuery for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var paramStr = window.location.search;
var params = paramStr.substring(1, paramStr.length).split('&');
var paramList = [];
for (var index=0; index < params.length; index++) {
    var param = params[index].split('=');
    paramList.push({name: param[0], value: param[1]});
}
</script>
```

The result:

```
[Object]0: Object
name: "a"
value: "b"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var url=new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        var params = [];
        for(var value of url.keys())
        {
            params.push({
                name: value,
                value: url.get(value)
            });
        }
```